# For loop in 'mustached' underscore template in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, underscore.js, mustache

I am using underscore with backbone in a jsp app.

In order to do that, I have used:

```
_.templateSettings = {
        interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
    };
```

in order to have mustache-like templates so as to avoid jsp conflict.

Until this point everything is ok (i.e. filled correctly templates with simple values).

Now, I am trying to add a for loop inside the template in order to show a json array.

So I added this code:

```
<script type="text/template" id="im-template">
<div class="row">                                       
    <div class="horizontal-scroll">
        {{ for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
            var template = data[i];
            alert(template.name);
        } }}
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

But when running the app, I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for
```

Do you know what could be the problem or how could I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're replacing the wrong regex, you want to replace the *evaluate* regex not the *interpolate* regex. From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> Define an **interpolate** regex to match expressions that should be interpolated verbatim, an **escape** regex to match expressions that should be inserted after being HTML escaped, and an **evaluate** regex to match expressions that should be evaluated without insertion into the resulting string.

Interpolation is used to replace a template token with the result of a JavaScript *expression* but a `for` loop is not an expression in JavaScript.

You want to replace the *evaluate* regex if you want to use a `for` loop like that:

```
_.templateSettings.evaluate = /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gaYRb/

Comment: Ooh, I see! Thank you very much! I 'll try it now, and let you know if everything is ok!

Comment: @Dimitris: you'll probably want to replace the other two regexes as well so that you can still use `{{= ...}}` for interpolation.

Comment: Yeap, exactly! interpolate was conflicting with evaluate. Thus I changed the interpolate attribute, and now everything is perfect! Thank you again very much!